# Encryption - Decryption between Java and React Js

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, encryption, cryptography

I am unable to create a successful encryption in React Js that can be decrypted in Java.

Below is the code --

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Row, Col, Typography, Spin } from "antd";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as Crypto from 'crypto-js';
import * as utf8 from 'utf8';
import { Calendar } from "antd";

class Test extends Component {
state = {};
componentDidMount = () => {
debugger;
var keySize = 0;
var ivSize = 16;
var saltSize = 16;
var iterations = 4096;

var pass = 'mysuperstrongpassword';
var passMac = 'mysuperstrongpasswordMac';
let message = 'Gurpreet';




const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")
var Crypto = new AES()

function AES() {}



AES.prototype.generateKey = function(salt, passPhrase) {
    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(passPhrase, CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt), { keySize: 256/16, iterations: 4096 });
    return key;
}

AES.prototype.encrypt = function(password, message) {
    var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
    var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, this.generateKey(salt, password), { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv) })
    var base64 = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
    return salt + base64.substring(0, base64.length-2) + iv
}

AES.prototype.decrypt = function(password, message) {
    var salt = message.substring(0, 32)
    var iv = message.substring(message.length-32, message.length)
    var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(message.substring(32, message.length-32) + "==")
    });
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipherParams, this.generateKey(salt, password), { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv) })
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
}

//var rest = btoa(hmac + result);

var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
var saltMac = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(20).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)
var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)


var macKey = AES.prototype.generateKey(saltMac, passMac)

var rest = AES.prototype.encrypt(pass, message)

var hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(passMac, macKey);

let result = hmac + salt + saltMac + rest;

let result2 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(result).toString();

var rest2 = btoa(result2);
console.log(rest2);
console.log(result2);
};

render() {
return (
<div className="test">
href={this.rest}
</div>
);
}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
return bindActionCreators({}, dispatch);
}
export default withRouter(
connect(null, mapDispatchToProps, null, { forwardRef: true })(Test)
);
```

Java

```
public class EncryptDecryptUtil {

    // private static final String CONTENT = "thisneedstobestoredverysecurely";
    private static final String PASSPHRASE = "mysuperstrongpassword";
    private static final String PASSPHRASEMAC = "mysuperstrongpasswordMac";
    private static final int IV_LENGTH = 16;
    private static final int AES_KEY_LENGTH = 16;
    private static final int MAC_KEY_LENGTH = 16;
    private static final int MAC_LENGTH = 20;
    private static final int SALT_LENGTH = 16;
    private static final int SALT_MAC_LENGTH = 16;
    private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 4096;
    private static final String AES = "AES";
    private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static final String SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    private static final String MAC_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA1";

    Cipher cipher = null;
    byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
    byte[] secretBytes = null;
    byte[] secretBytesMac = null;

    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM);
        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();

        byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_LENGTH];
        sr.nextBytes(salt);

        SecretKey secretKey = factory
                .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSPHRASE.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATION_COUNT, 256));
        secretBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();

        byte[] saltMac = new byte[SALT_MAC_LENGTH];
        sr.nextBytes(saltMac);

        SecretKey secretKeyMac = factory
                .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSPHRASEMAC.toCharArray(), saltMac, ITERATION_COUNT, 256));
        secretBytesMac = secretKeyMac.getEncoded();

        sr = new SecureRandom();
        sr.nextBytes(iv);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secretBytes, 0, AES_KEY_LENGTH, AES),
                new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] result = concatArrays(iv, concatArrays(saltMac, (concatArrays(salt, encrypted))));
        byte[] macResult = getMAC(secretBytesMac, result);
        result = concatArrays(macResult, result);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result);
    }

    public String decrypt(String cipherText) throws Exception {
        byte[] result = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);
        byte[] macResult = new byte[MAC_LENGTH];
        byte[] salt = new byte[SALT_LENGTH];
        byte[] saltMac = new byte[SALT_MAC_LENGTH];
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM);

        System.arraycopy(result, 0, macResult, 0, MAC_LENGTH);
        System.arraycopy(result, MAC_LENGTH, iv, 0, IV_LENGTH);
        System.arraycopy(result, MAC_LENGTH + IV_LENGTH, saltMac, 0, SALT_MAC_LENGTH);
        System.arraycopy(result, MAC_LENGTH + IV_LENGTH + SALT_MAC_LENGTH, salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);

        byte[] encrypted = new byte[result.length - (MAC_LENGTH + IV_LENGTH + SALT_MAC_LENGTH + SALT_LENGTH)];
        System.arraycopy(result, MAC_LENGTH + IV_LENGTH + SALT_MAC_LENGTH + SALT_LENGTH, encrypted, 0,
                encrypted.length);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM);

        SecretKey secretKeyMac = factory
                .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSPHRASEMAC.toCharArray(), saltMac, ITERATION_COUNT, 256));
        secretBytesMac = secretKeyMac.getEncoded();

        if (!MessageDigest.isEqual(
                getMAC(secretBytesMac, concatArrays(iv, concatArrays(saltMac, (concatArrays(salt, encrypted))))),
                macResult)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid MAC");
        }

        SecretKey secretKey = factory
                .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PASSPHRASE.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATION_COUNT, 256));
        secretBytes = secretKey.getEncoded();

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(secretBytes, 0, AES_KEY_LENGTH, AES),
                new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    }

    private static byte[] getDigest(byte[] mac) throws Exception {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        return digest.digest(mac);
    }

    private static byte[] getMAC(byte[] secretBytes, byte[] data) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(MAC_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(secretBytes, 0, MAC_KEY_LENGTH, MAC_ALGORITHM));
        return mac.doFinal(data);
    }

    private static byte[] concatArrays(byte[] first, byte[] second) {
        byte[] ret = new byte[first.length + second.length];
        System.arraycopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, ret, first.length, second.length);
        return ret;
    }

}
```

I cant change anything at Java Backend because for the iOS team they are able to encrypt-decrypt using this util and are sending us the correct strings.

But the issue is at Web end @React Js end - code above where we are unable to match the encryption technique same as Java.

Comment: what java version?

Comment: I would recommend you to isolate the issues by functionally dividing the Java and CryptoJS code and testing the parts successively. In the Java code a key is derived for the encryption and for the MAC. First check if the keys derived in the CryptoJS code are identical to those of the Java code when using the same salts and passwords. If so, next check if the ciphertext and MAC derived in the CryptoJS code are identical to those of the Java code when the same keys for encryption and MAC and the same IV are used. Then check the concatenated data (values and order).

Comment: Java version is 11 guys.. I tried to match all the parameters on React Js but not either getting the right decrypted string or invalid key length and invalid mac

Comment: `I tried to match all the parameters on React Js` This is not obvious from the code..  The parameters are different. E. g. in Java there is base64 encoded array with iv, ciphertext, mac where in React it's concatenated hex encoded values.  . Really print state after each operation and compare

Comment: Thanks gusto2. I'll try to match.